# pandas missing index.name after row added

Tags: python, pandas

The following looks like a bug to me :

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=['A','B'])
>>> df.index.name = 'some-name'
>>> df
                  A         B
some-name                    
0          0.841645 -0.088688
1          0.779664 -1.263692
2          0.058694  0.414090
>>> df.loc[3] = df.loc[1]
>>> df
          A         B
0  0.841645 -0.088688
1  0.779664 -1.263692
2  0.058694  0.414090
3  0.779664 -1.263692
```

If the index label is already present, the behaviour is as it should be:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=['A','B'])
>>> df.index.name = 'some-name'
>>> df.loc[2] = df.loc[1]
>>> df
                  A         B
some-name                    
0         -0.053362 -0.212953
1          0.300137  0.155986
2          0.300137  0.155986
```

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me in `0.19.2` `python 3` works nice.

Comment: works for me for `0.19.1` for `python 2.7`

Comment: works for me in 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: Mine is  '0.15.2' (python 2.7).
I guess I need to update. Thank you guys :)